# Adding custom AD properties to OAB

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

Is it possible to add custom Active Directory attributes to the Offline Address Book? I would like to configure, for instance, msExchResourceCapacity, to be distributed as an OAB property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link should help you out:

http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/resource-mailboxes-exchange-2010-part2.html

Fig. 13 shows what you're looking for.  This should be straight forward from 2010 through 2013.  Not sure for 2016.

-Chase